# How much data is in one cURL request

Tags: http, curl, upload, raspberry-pi, server

I will be sending simple data to a web server, most probably just as a GET request which will be:

- Latitude
- Longitude
- Speed
- Height
- deviceId

I could do this via SSH I suppose if it uses less data - but I cant see this being much.

So if i send this in myurl.com/parsedata.php?id=1&.... etc, how much data will it send require per request? the page will not load anything and it will do it over **cURL** or a similar protocol.

So, typically how much data will be in this per single request?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply run `curl` from the command line with `-v` option for verbose output and see the data which goes to the server and back. Here is what I get when I do a curl on this question's URL:

```
curl http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31789124/how-much-data-is-in-one-curl-request -v
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 104.16.103.85...
* Connected to stackoverflow.com (104.16.103.85) port 80 (#0)
> GET /questions/31789124/how-much-data-is-in-one-curl-request HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: stackoverflow.com
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Tue, 04 Aug 2015 08:51:53 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d89a0800ec97e30cad4dedad83d88e8dd1438678312; expires=Wed, 03-Aug-16 08:51:52 GMT; path=/; domain=.stackoverflow.com; HttpOnly
< Cache-Control: public, no-cache="Set-Cookie", max-age=60
< Cf-Railgun: 5107f6033d 18.60 0.037768 0030 4701
< Expires: Tue, 04 Aug 2015 08:52:53 GMT
< Last-Modified: Tue, 04 Aug 2015 08:51:53 GMT
< Vary: *
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< X-Request-Guid: 3f5aca8a-2715-4fcf-b68b-f71f85a620e0
< Set-Cookie: prov=fcd7db27-9d37-4235-afb6-5c3d76dc03f5; domain=.stackoverflow.com; expires=Fri, 01-Jan-2055 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
* Server cloudflare-nginx is not blacklisted
< Server: cloudflare-nginx
< CF-RAY: 210905e0082d03b8-SIN
<
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/QAPage">
... html content follows here ...
```

All the `>` lines are what is sent to the server as a request (as plain text over a socket connection) and the `<` lines are what is received back.

Comment: WIll this tell you how much data in terms of bytes is sent/recv'd?

Comment: Roughly yes... It depends on the encoding used and the actual characters sent, but in the typical case (utf-8 encoding) and using only the lower 127 codes (the english letters, numbers, punctuation, ...) each chararacter from the curl output corresponds to a single byte sent or received, so you can just count the number of characters above (including new lines).